# C++: Parse decimal from stream into uint8_t

Tags: c++, iostream

Is there a way to do the following directly using stream operators?

```cpp
uint8_t actual;
uint32_t temporary;
std::cin >> std::dec >> temporary;
if (temporary > UINT8_MAX) {
  // error
}
actual = static_cast<uint8_t>(temporary);
```

In particular, I would like to parse a sufficiently small decimal number into a `uint8_t` without resorting to a larger temporary variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a way to read a number directly into `unsigned char` with a `std::istream` ([`std::num_get::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) doesn't support `unsigned char`)

You could encapsulate it into a function:

```cpp
inline std::uint8_t read_uint8(std::istream& is) {
    unsigned short temporary;
    is >> temporary;
    if (!is) return -1;
    if (temporary > UINT8_MAX) {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return -1;
    }
    return std::uint8_t(temporary);
}


int main() {
    std::uint8_t actual = read_uint8(std::cin);
    if (!std::cin) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Or you can do something like what `std::put_money` or `std::osyncstream` does and wrap one of the arguments to call a custom `operator>>`:

```cpp
struct read_uint8 {
    std::uint8_t& v;
    read_uint8(std::uint8_t& v) : v(v) {}
};

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, read_uint8 v) {
    unsigned short temporary;
    is >> temporary;
    if (is) {
        if (temporary > UINT8_MAX) {
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        } else {
            v.v = std::uint8_t(temporary);
        }
    }
    return is;
}

int main() {
    std::uint8_t actual;
    if (!(std::cin >> read_uint8(actual))) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly stream the input into a `uint8_t` variable like so:

```
uint8_t actual;
std::cin >> std::dec >> actual;
```

If your input is too large, say you entered "12000", your `actual` variable will hold the value of `1`

Comment: What if the user types in 1? How do you tell the legitimate 1 from the bogus 1?

Comment: Check the failbit, take a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt
"If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set. For signed integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits<T>::max() or std::numeric_limits<T>::min() (respectively) is written and failbit flag is set. For unsigned integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits<T>::max() is written and failbit flag is set"

Comment: @kamshi: That seems to indicate that `actual` would hold `127` not `1`

Comment: @ben: According to cppreference, actual should contain 255 instead of 1, because it is unsigned. However, after I checked it in compiler explorer, it contains 49 (https://godbolt.org/z/41q6eax3P). I am pretty sure that this happens because std::uint8_t is treated as a character, not a number. If you parse to bigger types like std::uint16_t, it works. I am not aware of a way to achieve what op asked directly with streams, due to how std::uint8_t is handled by the stream operator.

Comment: It sounds like your answer is pretty convincing argument that you CAN'T "directly stream the input into a uint8_t variable".  You really need to wrap your logic in a function or class (like [Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71712158/421195) shows above) to correctly handle all conditions.

Comment: @kamshi: Correct on both counts, the type here is `uint8_t` so `numeric_limits<T>::max()` would be `255`, I had wrongly used `numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()`.  And `uint8_t` matches the `operator>>` overload for a single character, so it reads `'1'` (49) for "12" and "12000" alike, it has nothing to do with an input being out of range.